# SharePoint email an event to Oulook calendar

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

I am using a SharePoint calendar for people to Register for trainings. When people register for a training (adding an item to a list) I would like SharePoint to email a Meeting request to their Outlook email and add it to their Outlook calendar. Is there a way to do this? I know I can set a workflow to send an email but can it add the event to their Outlook calendar?

Answer (score 1):

You can send an email to the user with a link to download ics file. It won`t send ics file as an attachment but link in email will downloads the file.

Here is syntax

```
siteurl/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Cmd=Display&List={LIST GUID}&CacheControl=1&ID=itemid&Using=event.ics
```

You can refer the example in below link
https://ameyakawale.wordpress.com/2010/05/18/email-a-calendarappointment-link-using-sharepoint-workflow/

We have implemented this approach to customer which works great.

Answer (score 0):

They will need to "Connect to Outlook" for that Calendar. That's the best that SharePoint can do, but it will be a calendar they can view. Check out this link to learn more:

https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/sharepoint-connect-to-outlook/